# Pass in outer instance as implicit argument to method

Tags: python, class, parameters, state

Suppose I have a class MyClass with instance method my_method.

```
class MyClass:
     ...
     def my_instance_method(self, f):
          return f self
     ...
```

I want to be able to pass in a function f that may be an instance method of MyClass, or may contain an instance method of MyClass (for instance in a lambda or otherwise combined with other instance methods), but I don't want to pass in the instance into the argument function--I just want the argument function to assume that the "self" is the same as the "self" of the outer call, if the argument function requires an instance at all.

For instance,

`MyClassInstance.my_instance_method(MyClass.another_instance_method(args))`

I'm not sure how to best approach this in Python, but I feel like it's similar to how the State monad works in Haskell and how implicit parameters work in Scala. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You just call such a function or unbound method like any other function. Other arguments would have to be passed separately. In its most general form, it would look like

```
def my_instance_method(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

A call to this method might thus look like

```
m = MyClass()
# e.g. m.another_instance_method(3, "foo", bar=9)
m.my_instance_method(MyClass.another_instance_method, 3, "foo", bar=9)
```